# First Passage Time analysis in adehabitatLT returns only NA

Tags: r, geospatial, adehabitathr

*Background:* I try to do a First Passage Time Analysis in R using `adehabitatLT`. I found a good tutorial [here](http://www.r-gators.com/2018/01/31/wildlife-tracking-data-in-r/) and I can follow all the steps using my own data set up to the section with First passage Time analysis.

*Problem:* When I use the `fpt()` command i get a strange result where all the produced lists are filled with `NA` (except the list of my custom defined radii, where i tested the same values as the example, as well as larger ranges to see if that was the cause of the problem).

*My efforts:* I can successfully perform the analysis using the example data provided in the tutorial, so I have tried to compare my own data set with the ones provided in that example. I haven't been able to find any crucial differences. I have tried different radii and units in the `fpt()`-command. I have also performed the analysis on different subsets of my dataset, with the same result.

Unfortunately I cannot provide you with a workable example as my data is recorded from a protected species. So my question cannot be more specific than to ask if there are any more diagnostics I could run to detect potential causes of the problem. Or if there are any common mistakes that I might have run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was due to the projection used (found out thanks to [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-ecology/2010-April/001227.html)). I had positions in decimal latitude/longitude, and the radii I defined turned out to be in degrees rather than meter (since a degree at the equator is 11.32 km, I got sensible results if i divided my radii with 11320).

Converting to a UTM projection solved the problem.

I leave the question as a reference is somebody else make the same mistake.